# Creating (NonFirst Normal Form) object table using rows of another ordinary (2NF) table

Tags: plsql

The challenge:


From one table named CARS_TABLE with two columns, ID and Model with information like below: 

1    Ferrari

2    Audi

3    Mustang

After creating another table (in **this** **case**, named CARS_OBJECTS_TABLE) that only has 

only one column which is an object type which I\'ve done with the code below...

/

CREATE TYPE CAR_OBJECT AS OBJECT

    (ID number,

    Model varchar2(30))

/

CREATE TABLE Cars_Object_Table(

    Car_Column CAR_OBJECT)


-- now the challenge is to get the two columns, ID and Model, 

of the first table CARS_TABLE,  into the object column Car_column 

of the second table CARS_OBJECT_TABLE. 


So far, I have come up with the below, which does not produce an error, 

but does not populate the object column of the second table either.


CREATE TYPE CAR2 UNDER CAR (

    IDs number,

    Models varchar2(30),

DECLARE

    Car_Object CAR2;

    cursor importData is select * from cars_table;

BEGIN

    open importData;

    loop

    fetch importData into CAR2 (IDs, Models)

    **if** importData%found

        then

        insert into Cars_Object_Table    

        values CAR2 (IDs, Models);

    **else**

        exit;

    end **if**;

    end loop;

    close importData;

END;

/


Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in just SQL with an `insert .. select` statement. However you must first select your cars_table data into car_objects and then insert.

```
insert into cars_object_table
select car_object(id, model) from cars_table;
```